# find the x value where y is at its minimum value

Tags: r, min

im currently using the following script in an area under curve analysis:

min(data[,2])

to find the min value for my x axis, i would like to create another script which returns the x value where y is at its minimum value?

Cheers

Comment: `x[which.min(y)]`

Comment: Fantastic, cheers